# Failed to create AWS Linked Account Programmatically? Status Code: 400 Error Code: SubscriptionRequiredException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

*The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: AmazonAccountsService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: SubscriptionRequiredException)*

This output I get for my java code when I try to create Linked account programmatically.

Is their any policy or permission requires? and How can I subscribe for AmazonAccountsService?

Comment: Which API is this?  I assumed Billing & Cost Management, but I don't see an obvious action for what you're doing in the [API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/api-reference.html) for that service.  Also, are these new accounts?

Comment: It is not Billing & Cost Management API. It used to create new Linked Account

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs for the API you're calling?  Have you considered opening an Account Support request with AWS support?  You don't need a paid tech support contract to submit issues that appear to be related to your account's configuration, which is what this sounds like it *might* be.

Comment: No, I don't have privilege  to share. Can you tell me what are the steps to white-list AWS account